# Error using fcnchk

Tags: matlab

```
a=2;
b=9;

syms x
I0=besseli(0,a*x/b);

F(x)=(x/b)*exp(-(x^2+a^2)/(2*b));
FUN=x*F(x);

mean=quad(FUN,0,100)
```

And i get this error:

```
Error using fcnchk (line 107)
If `FUN` is a MATLAB object, it must have an feval method.

Error in quad (line 57)
f = fcnchk(funfcn);
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument `FUN` to `quad` has to be a function, however you are providing a symbolic expression instead.

Try using `FUN = matlabFunction(x*F(x))` to convert your expression to a function.

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995486/how-do-i-make-a-function-from-a-symbolic-expression-in-matlab).