# How to find the derivative without using a symbolic function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, derivative

I would like to find the derivative of this function:

```
function [f] = f4(x) 
    f=0.5*(x(1)^2+10*x(2)^2);
end
```

I'm using symbols to find the jacobian:

```
x = sym('x', [2 1]);
f=0.5*(x(1)^2+10*x(2)^2);
grad=jacobian(f,x)
```

which returns

```
grad = [ x1, 10*x2]
```

Then I change it manually to look like this so I can use `feval`:

```
grad = [ x(1,1), 10*x(2,1)];
```

I find that using `feval` is faster than using `subs`. I would like to find the derivative of any function that I can evaluate using `feval` and avoid doing anything manually.

Comment: Do you want to take derivative without using symbols that usually we define in matlab by sym function?

Comment: I don't mind getting the derivative using symbols as long as the final function for the derivative is not a symbolic function and I didn't have to edit it manually.

Comment: So how exactly do you expect to get the function without symbols? In which form? `feval` is working for builtin functions or `.m`-file defined ones. There is no builtin functionality to write an m-file for you. But you can implement one using the symbolic toolbox. But it looks too awkward to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate the derivative of a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613859/calculate-the-derivative-of-a-vector) – in particular the third option in may answer,  Complex Step differentiation. See also this question: [numerical partial derivative in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20257508/2278029).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a function from a symbolic expression in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995486/how-do-i-make-a-function-from-a-symbolic-expression-in-matlab).